# Mavericks Finder spins when opening folders

Tags: finder, macos

Since upgrading to Mavericks, Finder sometimes hangs when I select a folder and am waiting for its contents to populate the window. This happens primarily in Open dialog boxes:

[image: Finder spinning]

It'll spin for about 15-30 seconds before showing the items in that folder. I can "Go to folder" and it'll usually show the contents immediately in that case. Why does it spin, and is there a way to make it faster? (It should be instant. I don't go to folders with thousands or even hundreds of items.)

Clarifications: These are just regular, local folders, usually in my home directory... not Remote Disc or network shares or anything fancy. It's an early 2013 Retina MBP, so it has a solid-state drive.

Answer (score 11):

There are a number of Apple Support Communities discussions regarding this, and a number of possible fixes given. To summarise in case one works for you:

- #### Disable Finder App Nap

  This seems to fix it for almost everyone on ASC who had Finder working fine in 10.8 but now is 'broken' in 10.9.

  ```
  sudo defaults write com.apple.Finder NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES
  ```

  …then log out and back in with 'Reopen windows when logging back in' disabled.
- #### Clear Finder Caches

  Empty `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.finder` and restart Finder.

  ```
  rm -r ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.finder/ && killall -HUP Finder
  ```
- #### Reset Finder Preferences

  Related to above — delete both preference files used by Finder:

  ```
  rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple/sidebarlists.plist
  ```
- #### Reindex Spotlight

  ```
  sudo mdutil -E /
  ```
- #### Change the 'Show Scroll Bars' setting

  It seems that it can be fixed by changing the scroll bar setting in System Preferences → General from When Scrolling to Always.
- #### Repair Permissions

  Try repairing permissions in Disk Utility.

Comment: Unfortunately these didn't solve the problem for me. But I like that there's a lot you can do to try!

Comment: Disable Finder App Nap solved it for me!

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand all the specific technical details, but this is apparently caused by [ISPs that perform NXDOMAIN interception](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?p=25982229#p25982229). Following that forum post, try running this in Terminal:

```
ping Backups.backupdb
```

If you *don't* get the following response:

```
ping: cannot resolve Backups.backupdb: Unknown host
```

...then your ISP *is* performing NXDOMAIN interception, which is causing the delay.

The procedure to disable the interception depends on your particular ISP. For instance, if you're using OpenDNS (which does interception by default), you can disable it in your account settings.

---

I was having this exact same problem on my machine, and I was using OpenDNS (but without an account, so I couldn't change the setting). I simply switched back to my ISP's (AT&T) default DNS – which apparently doesn't do interception, since I got the "correct" `ping` response above – and the problem immediately went away.

(I take no credit personally for this solution; I'm merely reporting it here for everyone else's benefit. It seems to be a very common issue with Mavericks).

Comment: No NXDOMAIN interception here, apparently. (Using Google's DNS.) Thanks for reporting it here!

Comment: Another piece of supporting evidence: after I made this change, the hangs completely stopped while on my home network, but reappear when I'm at work. I didn't have a chance to do the `ping` test when I was there, but clearly it's network related since it's the same machine in both places.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty interesting. Thanks, it fixed it for me, but now I am eternally curious as to what could be causing this hang. You wouldn't think DNS and Finder slowdowns are related at all.

Answer (score 2):

Note: though answer has now completely changed, this is just a late edit. I hope someone will benefit from this anyway.

Found a workaround which actually works, finally, from [OSXDaily](http://osxdaily.com/2013/11/24/slow-open-save-dialog-problem-mac-os-x/). To summarize, disabling network share automounting does the trick (at least for my few macs I've got Mavericks installed).

To disable network share automounting, open up Terminal.app and type in the following commands.

```
macbook:~$ sudo sh -c "cp /etc/auto_master /etc/auto_master.OLD && perl -i -pe 's/(^\/net)/#\$1/' /etc/auto_master && automount -vc"
```

What this does (for those less knowledge with command line, Bourne Shell and such) is that it first makes a backup copy of file `/etc/auto_master`, then edits one line of it and finally signals automounter to re-read `/etc/auto_master`.

After this you will have to manually mount your network shares. More information in original [OSXDaily article](http://osxdaily.com/2013/11/24/slow-open-save-dialog-problem-mac-os-x/).

Comment: Good thought -- I was wondering if generating previews for the icons was causing part of the problem. Unfortunately, I still get intermittent slow Finder behavior within apps, even for directories with just a few items in them.

Comment: I've experienced that too, but did get some help from the solution above. I've updated the answer as well to reflect the fact that it's far from 100% solution.

Answer (score 2):

Your snapshot shows that the [asynchronous progress indicator (throbber)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24435/whats-the-canonical-name-for-the-sunburst-waiting-animation) is the portion of the sidebar to draw:

- Connected servers
- Bonjour discoverable services
- Back to My Mac

You should be able to focus on the networking and isolate whether this is truly the action that is delaying your work or just an innocent bystander being the next thing to be drawn when the system is otherwise paused and delayed.

To troubleshoot this I would do the following:

1. Run sysdiagnose from terminal if I can reproduce the issue and see if I could catch a process using CPU or otherwise behaving different than an sysdiagnose when the system is otherwise idle. Skip this step if you don't like looking at system logs and going into terminal. This step may be valuable if you want to report this as a bug - the system shouldn't hang in my opinion to paint network services and should unblock the operation and show network devices later should that be slow.
2. Turn off all three items above in Finder preferences for the Sidebar.
3. Sign out of Back to my Mac
4. Disconnect from the network

Since there are several items this could be - hopefully you can narrow things down or comment if I missed a step or more information on the problem comes to light. Also, be sure you don't have any tools like Little Snitch or [Network Link Conditioner](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24066/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connections-on-the-mac) as they would clearly exacerbate the rendering of the network sharing portion of the sidebar if misconfigured.

Comment: I'd advise the same culprit hunt but in the following order: 4. (is this a network related problem, and  I feel it is :( ), 2., 3., 1. (this will the hardest to analyse right :( ).

Comment: I like to measure first, then intentionally change something and remeasure. I might not examine the logs in detail, but have them captured should the need arise. I agree disconnecting the network is a great triage step and just to try to identify something in step 1 as opposed to "do not continue unless you found something" :)

Comment: OK for step 1 first as a snapshot of a misbehaviour and a reference along the hunt.

Comment: This is indeed a clever idea. But I experience this delay on local folders and when disconnected from networks, so I don't think it's a network problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is it on every drive you have? Because if it is the same bahviour on different hardware? (Behavioural difference between a USB thumb drive and internal disk)

Is the "ls" command equally slow in terminal or instant? (try terminal and cd and drag an example folder into terminal and hit enter. Then type "ls" to see how long it takes to list the folders contents.)

- This could also be due to HFS+ corruption (run disk utility "verify disk" (not the permissions) and see if your (I guess your start up volume is affected) has issues. As it probably will, boot from recovery (hold down cmd+R on boot) and try to repair the disk with disk utility from there.
- Last but not least have you tried setting up a new user account and trying to reproduce it in a new user account?

Sorry for the many questions but I'm not (hopefully yet) allowed to comment on questions.

Comment: Thanks for contributing. `ls` is always instant. Interestingly, though, "Verify Disk" on my startup disk yielded a few errors: "Incorrect number of file hard link" and "Volume bitmap needs minor repair for orphaned blocks" and "Invalid volume free block count (It should be 43437880 instead of 40702664)" -- everything else is good. I'll try a repair and see if that helps...

Comment: I did the repairs and haven't seen the problem since (but it hasn't been very long yet) -- either way, it's a good thing to do, and your questions probed deeper into my problem. The bounty is expiring in a few minutes, so I awarded it to you, also as a welcome to the community. With a little more time I should be able to choose a best answer (if there is one that fixes it; but maybe Apple should just get on it!).

Comment: Phooey, it's still happening.

Comment: @Matt do you see anything related to my Answer?

Comment: ok, thank you very much!
Did you try making a new user account and analyzing whether this problem appears in a new local user, too?

Comment: @markhunte Yep, I up-voted it; but I wasn't able to find a FileStatsAgent process. And Hug, no, I'm on a work machine... haven't had a chance to do that yet.

Comment: Repairing disk solved my problem! Didn't think it could be corrupt in the first place. Really should be more upvotes to this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just seen this post on Tuaw.com [how-to-fixing-the-filestatsagent-bug](http://www.tuaw.com/2014/01/08/how-to-fixing-the-filestatsagent-bug/) by
[Erica Sadun](http://www.tuaw.com/editor/erica-sadun/)

Quote from tuaw.com post:

> At times, your system may seem to be spinning its wheels. A peek into
>   Activity Monitor (found in the Utilities subfolder of your
>   Applications folder) can offer clues as to what's going on....
>
> ..As I discovered, some Mavericks users may find a FileStatsAgent
>   process has been eating away at their CPU. If this happens to you,
>   it's generally due to a corrupt file.

They then go on to explain about using the open files and ports option in Activity Monitor on the process to see which files may be causing the problem.

This may or may not be your problem..

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem for a few weeks, trying every suggestion listed here and other forums but without success.... until tonight!

**TL;DR**: Run these 2 commands then reboot.

```
mv ${TMPDIR}/com.apple.IconServices{,-bad}
mv ${TMPDIR}/../C/com.apple.IconServices{,-bad}
```

**Long Version**:

The problem did not happen when I tried a newly created user account so it pointed to something with my profile.  I removed all the Preferences and Caches from my Library folder but the problem remained.

After examining the system logs, I noticed the following 2 errors would often appear when viewing a folder in the Finder.

```
12/16/14 12:24:29.908 AM com.apple.IconServicesAgent[244]: main Failed to composit image for binding VariantBinding [0x2af] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x3bf] - extension: mov, UTI: com.apple.quicktime-movie, fileType: ????.
12/16/14 12:24:29.908 AM quicklookd[8215]: Warning: Cache image returned by the server has size range covering all valid image sizes. Binding: VariantBinding [0xa03] flags: 0x8 binding: FileInfoBinding [0x903] - extension: mov, UTI: com.apple.quicktime-movie, fileType: ???? request size:16 scale: 1
```

These are related to creating/loading icons for different file types.  The Finder is hanging while attempting to draw the icons for the file listing so it made sense that it would lag if there were problems with the cache.
Since the IconServicesAgent isn't an application the user interacts with, the cache/prefs are not saved in the typical ~/Library/ folder but in a special hidden location used for OS-level apps and daemons.  Every user has a Cache and Temp folder in this location at `/var/folders/`.  We just need to locate and rename the IconServicesAgent's files.

When a user account is created, the system generates a folder here for the user but named with 32 seemingly random characters.  Since they are random, I can't give you an exact path but the TMPDIR environment variable can.  (If you want to know, run the command `echo $TMPDIR` to get the path to your own Temp folder.  It will be something like `/var/folders/jc/vzc51tfn2jzbzqkr9j3g38gm0000gn/T/` but we don't really need it.  The commands below will just use the variable directly)

Now rename the com.apple.IconServices folder in the T [temp] directory with this command.

```
mv ${TMPDIR}/com.apple.IconServices{,-bad}
```

Next we need to do the same in the Cache directory, which is in the same parent directory as the `T` directory.  This command will do what you need.

```
mv ${TMPDIR}/../C/com.apple.IconServices{,-bad}
```

So now reboot your Mac and after you log back in, the Finder should be quick again.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes have a similar problem: Finder is completely unresponsive, i.e., all Finder windows are frozen, and they all show the spinning beach ball.

In that case, for me the only thing that helped was to open Activity Monitor, and kill Finder (i.e., relaunch) it a number of times. Sometimes, I had to relaunch it up to 5 times.

(So far I haven't been able to pinpoint the culprit. I did not have any network disks mounted.)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in Yosemite. Some folders had their contents displayed just fine, others got the spin wheel. All folders in question were local folders, and their contents displayed fine with `ls` in the terminal.

What my problem seemed to be related to was having a network share connected prior to closing the lid on my laptop, then opening my laptop and connecting to a different network where that share was not available. The share was still shown in the left panel of the Finder window, but was not showing any contents. In the terminal `mount` still showed the share as mounted. With both Finder and the terminal open, I typed `umount /Volumes/USBSTORAGE` in the terminal. As soon as I did that, the Finder window became responsive and immediately listed the contents of the local directory that was selected.

It seems there's some code in Finder that gets blocked when dealing with remote storage that also blocks some local file operations.