# Finder freezes for several minutes when opening folder for first time after restart

Tags: macos, finder, macbook-pro, performance

After I restart my computer, if I try to open a folder the wheel at the bottom of the Finder window spins and I get the beach ball. This happens for several minutes (over 5 minutes) while loading the files. Finder is completely unusable during this time.

I have a MacBook Pro w/ Retina on 10.9 Mavericks.

What I have tried (using advice from [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107493/mavericks-finder-spins-when-opening-folders) question):
-Disable AppNap
-Clear Caches
-Reset Preferences

Also, my CPU usage is really high while it is trying to load. Any ideas what the problem could be?

**Update:**

**Activity Monitor screen shot:** [image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: Use the tools provided by Apple to give us more information. Open the Activity monitor and take a screen shot. Open the Console and copy paste some 30 lines.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: The boot drive is only about 50% full

Answer (score 2):

After further inspection, I noticed that when I first started Finder a process in Activity Monitor called InterCheck was taking up around 190% of my CPU (not sure how that's possible, but anyways).

A Google search revealed that that process is from Sophos Anti-Virus. It turns out that when I start Finder it is trying to live scan my entire disk, which is taking a really long since I had scan "inside archives and compressed files" checked. By unchecking this option, Finder loads much quicker and InterCheck spikes CPU usage briefly on start up and then goes back down to a reasonable level (which according to Sophos forums, is the normal behavior).