# Locate spinning pinwheel in Mavericks

Tags: macos

The loading-icon also known as Spinning pinwheel was located in an old Mac version at the following location:

> /Library/Frameworks/OpenBaseManager.framework/Versions/A/Resources/gear.tif

In Mavericks, this location does not exist. Where (if not renamed by Apple to something weird) is this file located in Mavericks? I've checked **~/Library** but it cannot find the **gear.tif** it used to be in the past.

Comment: Are you referring to the [asynchronous progress indicator](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24444/5472)? If not, a picture might be worth many words here...

Comment: the gearicon.tiff is here (but that is not the beach ball) /System/Library/Frameworks/Quartz.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/QuartzFilters.framework/Versions/A/Resources

Comment: @GeorgeGarside why is it necessary editing the TIFF in to TIF ?

Comment: @Buscar You edited it to be TIFF, this is not correct per the last time this file existed in its location in OS X.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside I would not know that since I do not have the older OSX any more. Where was it located in those OS ? Actually my search shows both so it really does not matter.

Comment: @Buscar It was located at the path in the question. Whilst I agree a single letter might not make a difference when reading the path, if you're actually attempting to find the file using the path with an extra t, it won't exist.

Comment: @Buscar웃 The Quartz.framework is not the beach ball I'm looking for. Thanks for the search though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one

It is called the Wait Cursor :)

/System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Versions/A/Resources

You can help looking for it, it does belong to the Cursor category.

Comment: Now I have to wait for a crash to check if that's the one. It looks different as I thought by the way..